# I want to pass data to another screen by FlatList in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation

Hello guys am new on react native I want to build an app like news app with posts,I stack in how to pass the data in flatlist to another screen to open the screen with the post data i use V6 navigation **Note** I do the Navigation and the post touchable this is my code :
the import :

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View ,Button ,FlatList,TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
```

Screen one :

```
function HomeScreen({navigation}) {
  const [news,setnews]=useState([
    {title:'React Native students can get the basic knowledge',by:'Chris brown',dateTime:'15 may',key:'1'},
    {title:'whats happening here is that you are trying to',by:'charley',dateTime:'15 jan',key:'2'},
    {title:'statuses. specifically, you have to look here:',by:'yami',dateTime:'15 jon',key:'3'},
    {title:'screen you want to show, when the authentication status changes.',by:'maria',dateTime:'15 nov',key:'4'},

  ]);
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      
      <FlatList
      data={news}
      renderItem={({item})=>(
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>navigation.navigate('Detials' ,item)}>
          <Text style={{fontSize:15,}}>{item.title}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )}
      />
      
    </View>
  );
}
```

screen two:

```
function DetialsScreen({navigation}) {
  
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>{navigation.getParam('title')}</Text>
      
    </View>
  );
}

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen  name="Detials" component={DetialsScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Comment: Typically for larger applications you would want to use a state management library such as Redux. Alternatively, you can use built in hook called Context to manage state: `https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext`

Comment: You don't need redux to pass a nav param. The v6 docs say that to access route params you need to use props.route.params.paramName

Comment: @windowsill he's using the param being passed to identify the correct item in his 'news' state. State needs to be lifted from HomeScreen to App component, or centralized with Redux, Context or other library.

Comment: @Hyetigran They are sending display data to a presentational component. Even if they build a whole redux, it wouldn't help them send navigation parameters. This question is specifically about sending navigation parameters and has nothing to do with state management. Please try to help answer the question.

Comment: @windowsill we should encourage and point out OP to use correct patterns. V6 route is not intended to pass whole objects. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/#what-should-be-in-params
Imagine if news grew to include article content, imageURIs, comments, etc.

Answer (score 0):

screenone :

```
  <FlatList
  data={news}
  renderItem={({item})=>(
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('ScreenTwo' , item)}>
      <Text style={{fontSize:15,}}>{item.title}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )}
  />
```

at screentwo you can get using `this.props.route.params`

```
export default class ScreenTwo extends Component {
  constructor(props, ctx) {
    super(props, ctx);
    this.state = {
      news: this.props.route.params
    };
  }

  render() {
    const news = this.state.news
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, margin: 30}}>
        <Text>Title is : {news.title}{'\n'}{'\n'}by {news.by}</Text>
        <Button
        style={{marginTop: 20}}
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}
          title="Back"
          color="#841584"
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

for snack you can try here : https://snack.expo.dev/@edoofx/example1111

im using class anyway :D

Comment: or you can set at screentwo directly if you want

`const news = this.props.route.params`